# Fill missing dates' data with zero when dataframe is merged

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

one = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
two = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
```

I wrote codes so,and one shows

```
A    Date
10    2011-01-03
20    2011-01-04
10    2011-01-06
20    2011-01-07
30    2011-01-10
40    2011-01-13
25    2011-01-15
・
・
・
```

two shows

```
B    Date
15    2011-01-01
15    2011-01-02
15    2011-01-03
25    2011-01-07
35    2011-01-10
10    2011-01-13
25    2011-01-15
・
・
・
```

I want to put 0 to  missing date’s data when data frame is marged.
Now I wrote codes

```
one_and_two = pd.merge(one, two, on='Date', how='inner')
print(one_and_two)
```

and run,one_and_two is

```
   　A        Date  　 B
0  10  2011-01-03  15
1  20  2011-01-07  25
2  30  2011-01-10  35
3  40  2011-01-13  10
4  25  2011-01-15  25
・
・
・
```

Ideal output is

```
   　A        Date  　 B
0  0  2011-01-01  15
1  0  2011-01-02  15
2  10  2011-01-03  15
3  20  2011-01-04  0
4  0  2011-01-05  0
5  10  2011-01-06  0
6  20  2011-01-07  25
7  0  2011-01-08  0
8  0  2011-01-09  0
9  30  2011-01-10  35
・
・
・
```

Dataframe has 2011-01-01 〜2011-12-31 ,
I want to put 0 to  missing date’s data ,but 
how can  I do it?What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: `one_and_two = pd.merge(one, two, on='Date', how='outer').fillna(0)` ?

Comment: @Rakesh That is what I thought, but missing dates (e.g. 2011-01-05) still need to be inserted and filled with zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use outer join with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by defined date ranges:

```
df = (pd.merge(one, two, on='Date', how='outer')
        .fillna(0)
        .sort_values('Date')
        .set_index('Date'))

df = (df.reindex(pd.date_range('2011-01-01', '2011-12-31'), name='Date'), fill_value=0)
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(columns=['A','Date','B']))
```

Or by minimal and maximal dates:

```
df = (df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), name='Date'), fill_value=0)
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(columns=['A','Date','B']))
print (df)
       A       Date     B
0    0.0 2011-01-01  15.0
1    0.0 2011-01-02  15.0
2   10.0 2011-01-03  15.0
3   20.0 2011-01-04   0.0
4    0.0 2011-01-05   0.0
5   10.0 2011-01-06   0.0
6   20.0 2011-01-07  25.0
7    0.0 2011-01-08   0.0
8    0.0 2011-01-09   0.0
9   30.0 2011-01-10  35.0
10   0.0 2011-01-11   0.0
11   0.0 2011-01-12   0.0
12  40.0 2011-01-13  10.0
13   0.0 2011-01-14   0.0
14  25.0 2011-01-15  25.0
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.I think your codes's output is missing 2011-01-05.I want to fill all date from  2011-01-01 to 2011-12-31 to output.

Comment: @user10102827 - Give me a sec.

Comment: thank you for your answer.What is df in your codes in the case of mine?

Comment: @user10102827 `df` is `one_and_two `

Answer (score 2):

Use an outer join to capture all dates, reindex to the range between the min and max dates to captures all dates within the range, fill null values with zero, and then finally reset the date index and rearrange in the desired order (`A`, `Date`, `B`).

```
one_and_two = (
    pd.merge(one, two, on='Date', how='outer')
    .set_index('Date')
    .reindex(
        pd.DatetimeIndex(
            start=one_and_two.index.min(),
            end=one_and_two.index.max(),
            freq='D',
            name='Date'))
    .fillna(0)
    .reset_index()
    [['A', 'Date', 'B']]
)
>>> one_and_two
     A       Date   B
0    0 2011-01-01  15
1    0 2011-01-02  15
2   10 2011-01-03  15
3   20 2011-01-04   0
4    0 2011-01-05   0
5   10 2011-01-06   0
6   20 2011-01-07  25
7    0 2011-01-08   0
8    0 2011-01-09   0
9   30 2011-01-10  35
10   0 2011-01-11   0
11   0 2011-01-12   0
12  40 2011-01-13  10
13   0 2011-01-14   0
14  25 2011-01-15  25
```